# How to programmatically back out of a drag-drop operation in a QListWidget?

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt, qlistwidget

I'm using a QListWidget that simply displays a list of objects. I allow the user to reorder these items via internal drag and drop. Everything works, but I now need to add a check when the user tries to drop (reorder) and if the check fails, re-establish the original order programmatically. Here's what I've got:

```
class SequenceControl(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(SequenceControl, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initialIndex = 0
        self.selectedObject = None
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)


    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        super(SequenceControl, self).dragEnterEvent(event)

        self.selectedObject = self.currentItem()
        self.initialIndex = self.currentRow()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        super(SequenceControl, self).dropEvent(event)

        # Some logic here (not shown) to see if the drop is not 
        # allowed. Assume it isn't:
        warningDialog = MyWarningDialog(self.parent)
        ProceedAnyway = warningDialog.exec_()

        if ProceedAnyway:
            # Do stuff...
        else:
            # Here's the problem. I need to place the item being dropped
            # back in its initial pre-drag/drop location. The following
            # naïve attempt doesn't work:
            self.insertItem(self.initialIndex, self.selectedObject)
```

The above is definitely wrong (I believe) because it may duplicate the item. But aside from that, the problem is that it appears to have no effect. I think the drop event is overriding anything I'm doing in terms of reordering. But that's just a theory. Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To revert the change we must first remove the target item, for this we use `takeItem()` that besides removing it will return the item, then insert it in the source position with the help of the `insertItem()` function.

```
class SequenceControl(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SequenceControl, self).__init__(parent)

        self.fromPos = None
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        super(SequenceControl, self).dragEnterEvent(event)
        self.fromPos = self.currentRow()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        super(SequenceControl, self).dropEvent(event)

        reply = QMessageBox.question(None, "Revert to Drag and Drop",
                                     "Do you want to keep the change?",
                                     QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            print("Do stuff...")
        else:
            currentItem = self.takeItem(self.currentRow())
            self.insertItem(self.fromPos, currentItem)
```